# Web Audio API - USB Hub

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, web-audio-api

I'm using [Web Audio API](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/) to create sounds and playing it to output devices.

This [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/itamarsh/yr6pc20h/4/), let you connect to two output devices, and play a tone on each one.

This is working fine with both default output and USB outputs.

The problem starts when using two USB outputs connected to a PC with USB Hub (no external power).

After playing a while (and using the PC for other tasks, thus creating some workload) the sound breaks in one or both of the outputs

I am looking for a way to understand why its happening.
Any help would be appreciated.

(Also tried [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/itamarsh/yr6pc20h/2/) approach, it was worse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching to both Chrome team, Web Audio API team and the use sound card's teams, We realized this is a problem with the sound card itself, not fitted to be used with multiple sound card connected